# Quotation marks do not work in Bing?

Tags: bing

The query ["moscow is a beautiful city"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%22moscow%20is%20a%20beautiful%20city%22) does not return any results containing the exact search phrase (compare to [Google's response](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22moscow%20is%20a%20beautiful%20city%22)). Is it a bug in Bing and are there any workarounds?

And screenshots:

[image]

vs.

[image]

Comment: I just checked and it works.

Comment: Please look at the screenshots: [bing](http://bayimg.com/gaKkEAadB) vs [google](http://bayimg.com/GAkKHaAdb). All results on the first page from google contain the exact search phrase. No results on the first page from Bing do that.

Note also the number of hits: 7.2M (bing) vs 37k (google).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the `market` parameter.

See the [Bing API 2.0 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251064.aspx):

> The market parameter is optional. If the parameter is not specified, the API will attempts to determine an applicable market through the use of logic such as the IP address of the request, cookies. and other elements.

Compare two results for the same query using different `market` option values: [en-US](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%22moscow%20is%20a%20beautiful%20city%22&market=en-us)  vs [ru-RU](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%22moscow%20is%20a%20beautiful%20city%22&market=ru-ru). Each result on the first page of the answer for the en-US market contains the exact query string, while for ru-RU no result does.

Answer (score 5):

Just put a plus before the first quote:

> +"Moscow is a beautiful city"

[Click here to try it](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%2B%22Moscow%20is%20a%20beautiful%20city%22).

Sometimes this works perfectly. Other times, it lets through a few false positives. Other times, it lets through a lot. But it always seems to work better than anything else you can do (certainly better than any other suggestion here so far).

Another tip: Capitalizing "Moscow" seems to make it work slightly better.

Bing's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795609.aspx) does claim that putting a phrase in quotes

> Returns results that contain the specified phrase, exactly.

Therefore, needing to put a plus at the beginning is clearly a bug - just one of many in Bing that MS apparently doesn't care to fix.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have been able to tell over the YEARS, Bing has never worked using quotation marks.  Still does not.  Always bothered me.  One of the main reasons I go back to Google when Bing fails me.
If relevant, I use Firefox.
My post is as of today's date of August 5, 2014 CE.

Comment: This contradicts what the other answers say.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  I cannot get Bing quotes to work for exact phrases, except for maybe the first couple of results on page one.  I've tried various browser versions, different IP addresses, to no avail.  Google works properly for exact phrases, Bing does not.

Answer (score 1):

Quotations *do* search by exact phrase. See the Bing documentation [Search effectively](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff524480.aspx) that states:

> Search for exact phrases by placing the search words within quotation
>   marks. For example, "short evergreen tree."

Check that you don't have unusual settings or filters in your [Bing settings](http://www.bing.com/settings.aspx).

Comment: I see, they _search_, but seem not to _return_ any results containing the exact phrase. Please look at the screenshots in the comment above. I checked the settings and found no unusual ones.

Comment: Have you tried the "Advanced" link in the search results? (I doubt that will change anything, but you can try.) What country are you in, and language settings? In US-en it is returning results for me that match the exact phrase you used. The next step may be speaking with bing support directly?

Comment: Mufasa, thank you for the response. I sorted it out and posted the answer. Language settings are the key.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution. You can use the inbody: parameter so that Bing does not separate your search string into multiple words.

Try searching in Bing for inbody:Moscow&is&a&beautiful&city

Also works as inbody:Moscow+is+a+beautiful+city

[image: using inbody: parmeter in Bing]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

The only way that the Bing API returns the same results for an exact phrase is to put another double quotes in the query (in REST invokes it seems that is not needed to escape the quotes). I tried first this URL:

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27google%20api%20news%27&$format=json&$top=3
```

The results were diferent. Next I tried this other:

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27%22google%20api%20news%22%27&$format=json&$top=3
```

With the second one the results were the same as that in the Bing web search with "google api news" phrase.

Comment: Links that need a username and password do not offer help.  Please post screenshots or just the actual search queries that anyone could type into the services to see result set.

Answer (score 0):

Google no longer searches for exact matches when you enclose all terms within quotation marks. It just returns every thing that has both terms but located separately anywhere in the document.

Comment: I just found a way to get exact matches (at least with words if not with punctuation marks): To find "French ogival" (with the "French" and the "ogival" actually together), type: 'allintext: "French ogival" '. ...Put the expression "allintext" with a colon, then space, then your term in quotes. It works pretty good. I found it here: https://www.lifewire.com/looking-for-specific-phrase-3482479 .

Comment: This is false. And also, this question is not about Google search; it's about Bing search.