# Combination of quotations and OR do not work in Bing Search

Tags: search, search-engine, bing

To proceed on the question posted here: [Quotation marks do not work in Bing?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/quotation-marks-do-not-work-in-bing)

I want to make a combined search for two variations of the same sentence.
It could be for instance:

Query: "moscow is a beautiful city" OR "london is a beautiful city"

If you try out this composite search in Bing (either bing.com or the API) it does not work. A lot of irrelevant results are returned.

If the two searches are done individually, it works well.

Any ideas how I can achieve this search? I am developing an app that searches with the commercial Bing search API so I want to limit the total number of searches done by combining some of them.

Comment: Still the same problem in 2020 ...